# Best way to host a ReactApp with real-time updates support

Tags: reactjs, websocket, hosting

I'm building a react app and I was wondering which was the best way to host it. I need to support web sockets protocol since I will be using GraphQL subscriptions. I considered S3 + Cloudfront but as far as I understand S3 doesn't support real-time updates and also Cloudfront doesn't support brotli (even though I've seen some workarounds for this issue using lambda@edge). So, what is the best alternative to host my app?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about any special requirements for your app but I have been using Heroku https://www.heroku.com/what for a while for testing react apps with web sockets and suscription from graphql and everyting works fine